# How to convert the ggplot2 text size to R's own plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, text, font-size

This may seem like a simple question, but I couldn't get any information on the sites I looked at.

In `ggplot2` I use text size 7. For some reason I needed to use R's native graphics, but I don't know how to scale the text size to match `ggplot2`.

The text size of my axes is:

`theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 7)`

Within `plot()`, what value of `cex.axis` should I put?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly are you saving/combing plots to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could get the default ggplot using `(theme_bw()$text$size)` -> 11

Font size 7 is then 64% smaller then the default -> 7/11 (in my first answer I used 12).

To scale the font size to match your ggplot2 font size of 7, we could  a scaling factor of 0.64

```
dev.off()
barplot(data$mpg, names.arg = data$cyl,
        col = "grey", border = "black",
        main = "Title", xlab = "X Axis", ylab = "Y Axis", 
        cex.names = 0.64,
        cex.lab = 0.64,
        cex.main = 0.64,
        yaxt="n",
        xaxt="n")
axis(2, cex.axis = 0.64)
axis(1, cex.axis = 0.64)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, how did you come up with 0.58 to match with ggplot text size 7? And par should be called before barplot?

Comment: Please see my update. Now it should be clear. The default was not 12, it was 11. But I think it depends on the theme we choose.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that it would be in specifying the parameters for the base plot, e.g. specifying "par(ps=7)" before the plot, where ps is "integer; the point size of text (but not symbols)."

Alternatively, I know when you go to save the plot using something like "png()" there is an option of specifying pointsize. So when I try the following and scale the plots to be the same, the axis font looks similar. You could mess around with margins etc.. to avoid having to scale.

```
foobar <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))

p_gg <- ggplot() + theme_light() + 
  geom_point(data=foobar, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 7))
ggsave(p_gg, file="p_gg.png", width = 4, height = 4, units ="in", dpi = 600)

png(filename = "p_df.png",
    width = 4, height = 4, units = "in", pointsize = 7,
    bg = "white", res = 600, restoreConsole = TRUE)
par(new=TRUE, ps=7)
plot(foobar$x, foobar$y)
dev.off()
```

[image]